# How to use string matrices in inline assembly c++

Tags: c++, assembly, masm, inline-assembly

I am given a task to transliterate from Cyrillic to Latin using inline MASM.
I've written the following code, which now can process only simple sounds, like 'a', 'b' and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <clocale>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    char map[33][4] = { "a",
    "b"
    , "v"
    , "g"
    , "d"
    , "e"
    , "z"
    , "z"
    , "i"
    , "i"
    , "k"
    , "l"
    , "m"
    , "n"
    , "o"
    , "p"
    , "r"
    , "s"
    , "t"
    , "u"
    , "f"
    , "h"
    , "c"
    , "tch"
    , "sh"
    , "sch"
    , ""
    , "yy"
    , ""
    , "ae"
    , "yu"
    , "ya" 
    };

    char str_out[160];
    char str_in[80];
    cin.getline(str_in, 80);

    _asm
    {

        lea esi, str_in;
        lea edi, str_out;

    Process:
        lods 
        cmp al, '\0';

        je End_String;
        cmp al, 223;
        jb Write_Symbol;

        // russian а stands for == 224

    translit:
        mov ebx, esi;
        mov ecx, edi;
        xor edi, edi;
        lea esi, map;
        movzx edi, al;
        sub edi, 224
        mov al, [esi + edi*4]; // **loads only first character**
        mov esi, ebx;
        mov edi, ecx;
        jmp write_symbol;

    Write_Symbol:
        stos;
        jmp Process;

    End_String:
        stos;

    }

    cout << str_out << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

But problem starts when I need to deal with complex sounds like 'tchi', 'cha' , etc.
Basically the task is load a start of corresponding string using esi and edi registers and call system to please print me a string, but I don't understand how to do it, how to load an address of such a string and invoke syscall.

Comment: You can do a dword load since you know you have 4 bytes.  You could `bsr` and divide by 8 rounding up (using add and right shift) to find out where the highest non-zero byte is, i.e. how many bytes to actually copy to the destination buffer.  (Actually just do a 4-byte store and increment the pointer by that many; 1-byte outputs will overlap by 3, but that's fine.)

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @Peter Cordes, I solved my task :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <clocale>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
char map[33][8] = { 
    "a...",
    "b..."
    , "v..."
    , "g..."
    , "d..."
    , "e..."
    , "z..."
    , "z..."
    , "i..."
    , "i..."
    , "k..."
    , "l..."
    , "m..."
    , "n..."
    , "o..."
    , "p..."
    , "r..."
    , "s..."
    , "t..."
    , "u..."
    , "f..."
    , "h..."
    , "c..."
    , "tch."
    , "sh.."
    , "sch."
    , "...."
    , "yy.."
    , "...."
    , "ae.."
    , "yu.."
    , "ya.."
};


int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    cout << &map << "\n";

    char str_out[160];
    char str_in[80];
    cin.getline(str_in, 80);

    int len = 0;

    _asm
    {
        lea esi, str_in;
        lea edi, str_out;

    Process:
        xor eax, eax;
        lodsb
        cmp al, '\0';
        je End_String;
        cmp al, 223;
        jb Write_Symbol;

        // я == 255

    translit:
        mov ebx, esi;
        mov ecx, edi;
        xor edi, edi;
        lea esi, map;
        movzx edi, al;
        sub edi, 224;

        mov eax, dword ptr [esi + edi*8];
        mov esi, ebx;
        mov edi, ecx;
        add len, 4;
        stosd;
        jmp Process;

    Write_Symbol:
        add len, 1;
        stosb;
        jmp Process;

    End_String:
        stosb;

    }

    str_out[len] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str_out[i] != '.') {
            cout << str_out[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's horribly inefficient (many 1-byte calls to `cout<<`), and destroys any `'.'` characters in the input.  Like I said, have the asm figure out how many bytes to increment the pointer instead of doing that later in C to skip "padding".  You also don't need `map[33][8]`, it can still be `map[33][4]` with implicit zero padding up to 4 for shorter string initializers.

Comment: Like I said, `bsr` would be a good way to find out how many characters are in the dword you loaded, if they're padded with zeros like in your original question.